# How to parse XML file in VBA macro on Mac OX

Tags: macos, vba, macros, ms-word

I am beginner in vba. I have started a project for mac ox now i need to read xml file. It is easy to ready xml file in vba on windows using `Microsoft.XMLDOM` API but as i know mac do not support any external dll or API library. So is there any way to ready xml file in VBA macro on mac. 
Thank in advance.

Comment: Maybe you can just use normal string handling? How much data do you need to pull from the XML?

Comment: @Jbjstam my xml contains large and complex data. I manage the find the solution by writing a translator java jar file which i call from my vba project, that retrieve and write simplified data into a text file and i read this text file in vba. Its work for me.

Comment: Thats a good solution :)